# How does this count work?

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, group-by

My query is given below:

```
select     vend_id,
           COUNT(*) as num_prods
from       Products
group by   vend_id;
```

Please tell me how does this part work - `select vend_id, COUNT(vend_id)` as opposed to `select COUNT(vend_id)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
select COUNT(vend_id)
```

That will return the number of rows where the vendor ID is not null

```
select     vend_id, COUNT(*) as num_prods
from       Products
group by   vend_id
```

That will group the elements by Id's, and return, for each Id, how many rows do you have.
An example:

```
ID          name       salary      start_date              city       region
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------------------- ---------- ------
          1 Jason            40420 1994-02-01 00:00:00.000 New York   W
          2 Robert           14420 1995-01-02 00:00:00.000 Vancouver  N
          3 Celia            24020 1996-12-03 00:00:00.000 Toronto    W
          4 Linda            40620 1997-11-04 00:00:00.000 New York   N
          5 David            80026 1998-10-05 00:00:00.000 Vancouver  W
          6 James            70060 1999-09-06 00:00:00.000 Toronto    N
          7 Alison           90620 2000-08-07 00:00:00.000 New York   W
          8 Chris            26020 2001-07-08 00:00:00.000 Vancouver  N
```

If you run this query, you will get One row for city, and you can apply a function (in this case, count) to that row. So, for each city, you will get the count of rows. You can also use other functions.

```
SELECT     City, COUNT(*) as Employees
FROM       Employee
GROUP BY   City
```

The result is:

```
City       Employees
---------  ---------
New York           3
Toronto            2
Vancouver          3
```

as you can compare the numbers of rows for each city

Comment: "... will return the number of rows" _where the vendor ID is not null!_

Answer (score 0):

When you simply select `COUNT(vend_id)` with no `GROUP BY` clause, you get one row with the total count of rows with a non-NULL vendor ID - that last bit is important and is one reason why you may prefer `COUNT(*)` so as to avoid "missing" rows. Some people may argue that `COUNT(*)` is somehow less efficient but that's true in no DBMS I've used. In any case, if you *are* using a brain-dead DBMS, you can always try `COUNT(1)`.

When you group by `vend_id`, you get one row per vendor ID with the count being the number of rows for that ID.

In step-by-step detail (conceptually, though there are almost certainly efficiencies to be gained by optimising), the first query:

```
SELECT COUNT(vend_id) AS num_prods FROM products
```

- Get a list of all rows in `products`.
- Count the rows where `vend_id` is not NULL, then deliver one row containing that count in the single `num_prods` column.

For the grouping one:

```
SELECT vend_id, COUNT(vend_id) AS num_prods FROM products GROUP BY vend_id
```

- Get a list of all rows in `products`.
- For each value of `vend_id`:

  - Count the rows matching that `vend_id` where `vend_id` is not NULL, then deliver one row containing the `vend_id` in the first column and that count in the second `num_prods` column.

Note that those rows with a null `vend_id` do not contribute to the aggregate function (`count` in this case).

In the first query, that simply means they don't appear in the overall total.

In the second case, it means that the output row still exists but the count will be zero. That's another good reason to use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`select vend_id` will only select the `vend_id` field, where `select *` will select all the fields

Comment: Can you give a step-by-step explanation of what is happening ?

Comment: Yes, but nowhere is `vend_id` or `*` selected, only counts are taken.

Comment: (@paxdiablo, `vend_id` is actually selected, but your point stands.)

Answer (score 0):

`select vend_id, COUNT(vend_id)` and `select COUNT(vend_id)` gives same result for the count column as long as you use `group by vend_id`. when you use `select vend_id, COUNT(vend_id)` you must group by it using `vend_id`

Comment: They may give you the same number in the count column but they most assuredly _don't_ give the same result, unless your idea of "result" is markedly different from mine :-) The column counts differ.